# How do I make Perl code DWIM with UTF8?

Tags: perl, utf-8

The utf8 pragma and utf8 encodings on filehandles have me confused.  For example, this apparently straightforward code...

```
use utf8;
print qq[fü];
```

To be clear, the hex dump on "fü" is `66 c3 bc` which if I'm not mistaken is proper UTF8.

That prints `66 fc` which is not UTF8 but Unicode or maybe Latin-1.  Turn off `use utf8` and I get `66 c3 bc`.  This is the opposite of what I'd expect.

Now let's add in filehandle pramgas.

```
use utf8;
binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)';
print qq[fü];
```

Now I get `66 c3 bc`.  But remove `use utf8` and I get `66 c3 83 c2 bc` which doesn't make any sense to me.

What's the right thing to do to make my code DWIM with UTF8?

PS  My locale is set to "en_US.UTF-8" and Perl 5.10.1.

Comment: Check out the Unicode chapter in the latest edition of _Effective Perl Programming_. It's in Safari Online's Rough Cuts :)

Comment: Late to the party, but I would really suggest reading Juerd's "perlunitut" and "perlunifaq" perldocs to anyone who wants to get up to speed with character encoding in Perl quickly. They're pretty new (added in 5.10.0 and 5.8.9) so old hands who've "read every perldoc" might not know they're there :)

Answer (score 6):

`use utf8;` states that your source code is encoded in UTF8. By adding

```
binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)';
print qq[fü];
```

you are asking that the script's output be encoded in UTF8 as well.

If you had written

```
print "f\x{00FC}\n";
```

you would not have needed `use utf8;`.

Comment: To be safe I have to turn on utf8 both in the code and in every filehandle I might write to?  Any way to make that magically happen?

Comment: `use open ":encoding(utf8)"; use open ":std";` appears to be the necessary magic.

Comment: As Sinan wrote: You have to turn on utf8 to tell Perl that your source code is using UTF-8. You have to encode text written to your write filehandles and decode text read from your read filehandles if your files contain UTF-8.

Comment: If you're running on other people's systems, you probably want `use open ':locale';` so you'll respect their settings.  They may not want UTF-8.  (Note that `:locale` implies `:std`.)

Answer (score 0):

`use utf8;` simply indicates that your source code (including string literals) is in UTF-8.  You also need to set the encoding of your input & output streams.

You probably want to set the `PERL_UNICODE` variable in your environment.  I set it to `SAL`, which breaks down like this:

- **S** `STDIN`/`STDOUT`/`STDERR` are UTF-8
- **A** `@ARGV` is UTF-8
- **L** but only in a UTF-8 locale

See [PERL_UNICODE](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL_UNICODE) and [the `-C` option](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2A-C-%5B_number/list_%5D%2A) in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

You can also use [the `open` pragma](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?open) to set a default encoding.

If you're doing this in a module that you're distributing to others, you probably want

```
use open ':locale';
```

so it won't unexpectedly turn on UTF-8 for people who don't use a UTF-8 locale.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd use that but I have to do this as part of a module.  That appears to be necessary at startup time.